# REST services taking more time on IE10 and 11 - 20 seconds difference than chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm working on AngularJS SPA. It works with many REST services and I'm facing a weird issue with IE10 and 11.

2 REST services are behaving weird in IE 10/11 and take more than 20 seconds for respond. Same services responds in 2 seconds in chrome.

Is this a browser issue, because I don't think server behave different for calls being made from IE or Chrome.

Comment: IE has some max-connection settings that limit it unless you go in and tweak your registry, it may be holding off on sending the requests.

Comment: 2 seconds is already high ...